# Merging several text files line by line in python

Tags: python

I'm a network engineer by trade, new to python, and this question will be applied to access lists on routers but for simplicity I am going to use States and Cities.

I have several text files (two below) that contains lines of States and Cities as shown:

File1

```
Texas
Austin
Dallas
Houston
San Antonio
```

File2

```
Texas
Amarillo
Austin
Dallas
San Antonio
Waco
```

I need to merge these two files and spit out a new text file that looks like the one below:

```
Texas
Amarillo
Austin
Dallas
Houston
San Antonio
Waco
```

The positioning has to be precise in such a way that since file1 is missing Amarillo compared to file2, and file2 has Amarillo on top of Austin, then merged file will have Amarillo on top of Austin or below Texas in the resulting file. The same thing applies if it was the other way around where file2 is missing some cities compared to file1.

I'm not too sure how to start this script. A guiding hand would be appreciated!

thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried to do?

Comment: You could start by reading the contents of the two files into two lists. It's not relevant to the problem that this data is stored in a file. It takes minimal effort and reduces the scope of your question. We really don't want to have to teach you how to read and write files.

Comment: I've been using PyCharm to create some of the simpler scripts and there is a tool on there that lets you compare two files and then merge. I'm able to get my goal done through it but I have several files to merge so it's not scalable.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I understand that you don't want to teach how to read and write files. And that's ok. I do have simpler scripts that parse through router configs and write out to a file with anything I want. Now my next goal is to compare them and merge. I just started with Python so a bit of help would be nice. But if it's a bother, that's ok too.

Comment: Would you mind if I went ahead and edited your question so that the data is provided as two lists rather than two files?

Comment: I'm not too sure if presenting the question as two lists would give it context. But I guess that would make it clear. Go ahead. The data, before I write them out to files, are already on dictionaries with key as the "state" and values as cities (list). Just wasn't sure how to move forward with actual merging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one simple way to do it:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
from sys import exit


def w(data, title):
    with open('f3.txt', 'w') as file_out:
        file_out.write(title + '\n')
        for line in data:
            file_out.write(line + '\n')

def r(path):
    with open(path) as file_in:
        lines = file_in.read().split('\n')
    return [l for l in lines if l]


def combine(path1, path2):
    f1 = r(path1)
    f2 = r(path2)
    title1 = f1.pop(0)
    title2 = f2.pop(0)
    # ensure Texas is the first line in each file
    if title1 != title2:
        print("Titles do not match")
        exit()
    w(sorted(set(f1 + f2)), title1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    combine('f1.txt', 'f2.txt')
```

Here's the directory/file content before and after running:

```
james@rootVIII:~/Desktop$ ls
delete  f1.txt  f2.txt  test.py  utils
james@rootVIII:~/Desktop$ 
james@rootVIII:~/Desktop$ cat f1.txt 
Texas
Austin
Dallas
Houston
San Antonio
james@rootVIII:~/Desktop$ 
james@rootVIII:~/Desktop$ cat f2.txt 
Texas
Amarillo
Austin
Dallas
San Antonio
Waco
james@rootVIII:~/Desktop$ 
james@rootVIII:~/Desktop$ ./test.py 
james@rootVIII:~/Desktop$ 
james@rootVIII:~/Desktop$ 
james@rootVIII:~/Desktop$ cat f3.txt 
Texas
Amarillo
Austin
Dallas
Houston
San Antonio
Waco
```

Some things to note:

1. This expects "Texas" or the state name to be the first entry in each text file (f1.txt and f2.txt)
2. Turning a list into a set removes duplicates
3. The combine() method can accept a relative or absolute paths
4. The list comprehension `[l for l in lines if l]` returns a list without empty elements (because the string was split with a newline)... If split on whitespace you'll get San instead of San Antonio

Comment: I'll play with this one. Thank you!

Comment: Okay if it works just remember to mark answer as correct please and thank you :)

Comment: I can build upon this one. Thanks!